# modifying the "G" string formatter in C# to use exponents when number contains at least two zero d.p

Tags: c#, .net, string, formatting, string-formatting

Is it possible to modify the standard Numeric Format "G" so that the exponent is used when the number contains more than 2 zeros after the decimal place. If not, alternative solutions will be appreciated

e.g. `Console.WriteLine("{0:G}", -0.001960231155763821);`  outputs  1.96023115576382E-03

I cannot use the "E" formatter because for i have to also format double like 0.1326402168430582 for which the output should be 0.132640216843058

It seems that exponents are used in the "G" formatter when the number contains more than 4 zeros after the decimal place e.g. `Console.WriteLine("{0:G}", 0.000023);` outputs 2.3E-05

Comment: Hint: "standard" formatting would tend to suggest it's not modifiable.

Comment: Check the example in the MSDN Library article for IFormatProvider.GetFormat()

Answer (score 1):

You can write extension method.  Bellow is the code that you can copy and paste in LINQPad and run it.  Dump() method is LINQPad extension method.  So if you copy your code to VS, just ignore it.

```
void Main()
{
    var x = -0.00160231155763821;
    var x2 = 0.099;
    var x3 = -0.001;

    x.G2Format().Dump("x");
    x2.G2Format().Dump("x2");
    x3.G2Format().Dump("x3");
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static string G2Format(this double value)
    {
        var format = (0.01 > value) ? "{0:e}" : "{0:G}";
        return string.Format(format, value);
    }
}
```

It will gives you this result:

```
x
-1.602312e-003

x2
0.099

x3
-1.000000e-003
```

Is that what you are looking for?